# Copy all VCL control's properties values to another control with C++ Builder

Tags: controls, c++builder, vcl, copying

Is there any way to clone all properties values from one control to another in runtime (optionally without name property)?
For example TEdit edt1 has properties Text set to "Test1" and Font->Size set to 10. I want copy this values to TEdit edt2 without using:

```
edt2->Text = edt1->Text;
edt2->Font->Size = edt1->Font->Size;
```

because I don't know how many properties and which properties have been changed compared to default. Also I would like to use copying witch very different types of controls, not only TEdit.

Comment: There is no straight forward way to clone properties. You have to dig into RTTI for this.  There are third party cloning libraries available if you search around. Otherwise you have to write your own code to dig into each component's RTTI manually.

Comment: runtime or compile/design time? for the latter you just select all components in IDE where first selected component is the source and then in object inspector just hit `[enter]` when you are on property you want to copy to all other selected components ...